# Is this script safe to use?

Tags: php, ajax, chat

1- I found this script [most-simple-ajax-chat-ever](https://www.metachris.com/projects/most-simple-ajax-chat-ever/) during a browsing, I would like to add it to my `vBulletin` forum as a chat section with members and I would like to know if it safe to use it or not ?

2- Can I protect `chat.txt` from access via `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Please, refer to the [How-to-ask guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Apparently, you need to give more detail on the subject. Asking multiple questions in one is discouraged as well.

Comment: @Eduard Malakhov sorry i'll read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For quick reference:** It's safe but not secure. It's not the best way to end up with a chat system. You can check up other system which use database for storing and retrieving the messages. Of course you can protect the text file using .htaccess but believe me you shouldn't use this script.

**Detailed reference:** There are two  ways to follow up, one if you are a programmer then you should probably create own script for the same. You can use a MySQL database for the storage and probably a login system for different users. It will suck some time but you'll get something what is specially for you! If you have some bucks then you can get it professionally made.
The other way goes if you are not a programmer [which I think because you thought of taking a reference for the script] then you should check some good chat systems either open source or paid ones which have a better security and user management. I recommend using

- BoomChat @ http://www.myboomchat.com/boomword [It's worth a go!]
- Frug @ https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat [Heard a lot about it]